# What is the menu on the upper right corner called in Windows?

Tags: windows, user-interface

What is the menu on the upper right corner called in Windows?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to look this one up as well.

These buttons are called "Window Control Buttons".

[This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306280) support article from support.microsoft.com is also referring to them.